# how to color numbers after file_get_contents and echo $content;

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Excuse me for my bad description of what I am looking to learn.
I am new on coding sites.

I am trying to colorize the results of a variable.
If the value is bigger than zero then color should be red.

My code is the following:

```
$content="
    <h2>---3 HH and 3 LL FIBO--- </h2>
        <code>
            <pre>".htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents("$path/$file"))."</pre>
        </code>";
echo $content;
```

And the result is something like this:

```
Balance | Equity | Used Mr | Usable Mr, % |

38.610,21 | 65.781,67 | 19.900,00 | 69,75 | 

Symbol |Amount|S/B| P/L | Gross P/L | 

EUR/CAD | 500 | S | 201,2 | 7.687,34 |
```

Is it possible to color the numbers if they are bigger than zero?
Any ideas?

Comment: this codepen could be something for u: https://codepen.io/bramus/pen/kkpzZo

Comment: As long as you are only outputting this as one continuous text, you can not format individual parts of it at all (things like :first-line etc. aside). You would have to parse this in some way, so that you can insert HTML tags around those numbers at least, so that you have something that you can address individually to format it in the first place.

Comment: `if(is_numeric($content) && $content > 0) echo "<span class='red'>".$content."</span>";` with `CSS` you can style your class(es) then that color you want

Comment: The problem is that $content contains numbers and letters

Answer (score 0):

You can appy a preg_replace on your content to check for numbers and wrap it around  for exemple!

```
$regex = '/((?!0)\d+((\.|\,)\d+)*)/';    
$content="
    <h2>---3 HH and 3 LL FIBO--- </h2>
        <code>
            <pre>".preg_replace($regex, '<span class="color-red">$1</span>', htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents("$path/$file")))."</pre>
        </code>";
echo $content;
```

(Haven't tested but might work)

Comment: Well, I tried it with this exact code, it works. Have you made a class ".color-red" in your CSS? If not, well, that's why! But if you want, in the code, just replace the `class="color-red"` by `style="color: red"`. You will see the changes.